# "Module has no entry points defined", except it does (migrating the gwt-maven-plugin)

Tags: java, maven, gwt

`[INFO]    [ERROR] Module has no entry points defined`

I am migrating from org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin to net.ltgt.gwt.maven:gwt-maven-plugin, and I can't seem to convince the compiler that my module DOES have an entry point defined.

The old plugin could only work with older Java, which I don't have anymore... So I moved on to the newer incarnation of the GWT Maven plugin... Unfortunately this plugin uses parameters that GWT 2.0.2 compiler does not recognize (like -deploy or -sourceLevel)... Which forced me to change ${gwt.version} to 2.8.2. That's rather massive jump, but I don't see how that could invalidate something as simple as implementing the EntryPoint interface.

TheApp/Web/src/main/module.xml:

```
    <entry-point class='net.theapp.client.TheEntryPoint' />
...
    <source path='net/theapp/client'/>
    <source path='net/theapp/data'/>
```

Location of the entry-point class:

```
TheApp/Web/src/main/java/net/theapp/client/
  - TheEntryPoint.java
```

The class:

```
...
public class TheEntryPoint
    implements EntryPoint
{
...
```

Comment: You say your module file is .../module.xml.  Do you mean .../module.gwt.xml?

Comment: It may be useful to show how you configured the plugin in your pom.xml

Comment: @RobertNewton You nailed it sir. I completely missed that. Thanks! I have now moved to another error, but you nailed it. Please write a reply, so I can mark it as the answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have named your module file `module.mxl`.  The correct name is `module.gwt.xml`